# Unable to resolve; The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected

Tags: build.gradle

Recently i have uninstalled all JDK from my computer and installed new JDK. But my Android Studio is not building now. And showing following error.

```
Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre' but was: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
```

But in my android studio JDK path was set to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`. But not working.

Answer (score 0):

After so many tries finally i have resolved this issue by uninstalling JDK and installing recent version from my computer. And setting JAVA_HOME point to that recent version of JDK.